# open file with merge-change markers

Tags: git, vim, merge, diff

When you perform a merge in many version control systems (git, svn, perforce), one possibility is to get a file with unresolved "merge change markers" that looks something like this:

```
common part of the file

>>> ORIGINAL
print("hi there")
==== THEIRS
print("hi there joe")
==== YOURS
print("hi there susan")
<<<<

more common part of the file
```

Personally, I would prefer if the version control system just created these files and I could resolve them one-by-one at my leisure, using the difftool of my choice. Something like `vimdiff -m myfile.py`

How do you open a file like this as a 3-way merge in vimdiff? Can you do so in other tools?

### Edits

I just found [this](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/A_better_Vimdiff_Git_mergetool) which provides a script and links to several possibilities, including its own [script](https://github.com/whiteinge/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/diffconflicts)

Comment: Theres almost certainly an SO post on using vimdiff as git’s difftool (though i use fugitive.vim personally—also SO posts for that)

Comment: this isn't a question of how to use it as a difftool, but rather how to use it as a difftool on files that have already been created with "conflict markers"

Comment: Apologies—in that case you want to use it for git’s mergetool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @D.Ben Knoble mentioned, you want to use:

```
git mergetool
```

Which will open the editor set in Git's config with both sides of the conflict and the current file to be edited.

You can set the editor as follow:

```
[merge]
    tool = vimdiff
    conflictstyle = merge
```

As an extra, I use a lot the following mapping to navigate through conflicts markers:

```
nnoremap <leader>n /^\(<<<<\\|====\\|>>>>\)<CR>
```

Press `<leader>n` to search for the conflicts markers and then `n` or `N` to go from one to another.